# Wordnet Lemmatizer in R results in empty list

Tags: r, wordnet, sentiment-analysis, lemmatization

I have the following code to use the lemmatizer in R from wordnet, but the output is an empty list when the input vector is a string with more than one word.

Code used:

```
setDict("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WordNet\\2.1\\dict")


a <- c("the quality of the leather good, feels a texture, very love!")

finalresult <- lapply(a, function(x){
            x.filter <- getTermFilter("StartsWithFilter", x, TRUE)
            terms <- getIndexTerms("NOUN", 1, x.filter)
            sapply(terms, getLemma) }
        )

> finalresult
[[1]]
list()
```

How can I overcome this?
Thanks in advance!